# Merging 9 Sequential Variables into 1 Variable

Tags: python

I have nine variables below and a function, however I'm focusing on the variable part for this question. (The first nine lines of this code.)

```
groceryfruits1 = 'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 1.'
groceryfruits2 = 'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 2.'
groceryfruits3 = 'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 3.'
groceryfruits4 = 'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 4.'
groceryfruits5 = 'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 5.'
groceryfruits6 = 'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 6.'
groceryfruits7 = 'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 7.'
groceryfruits8 = 'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 8.'
groceryfruits9 = 'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 9.'

def checkout(itemcount, category):
    if category == "fruits":
        if itemcount == 1:
            print groceryfruits1
        elif itemcount == 2:
            print groceryfruits2
        elif itemcount == 3:
            print groceryfruits3
        elif itemcount == 4:
            print groceryfruits4
        elif itemcount == 5:
            print groceryfruits5
        elif itemcount == 6:
            print groceryfruits6
        elif itemcount == 7:
            print groceryfruits7
        elif itemcount == 8:
            print groceryfruits8
        elif itemcount == 9:
            print groceryfruits9

checkout(9, "fruits")
```

Since there are a sequential list of variables and it would be more orderly to have all the variables be in one line, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Any time you find yourself creating numbered variables like that, you should think about using an array (these are called lists in Python).

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the code to:

```
groceryfruits = 'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: {}.'

def checkout(itemcount, category):
    if category == "fruits":
        print groceryfruits.format(itemcount)

checkout(9, "fruits")
```

Answer (score 3):

The string preceding the fruit count is always the same, so why not just code that into your function?

```
def checkout(itemcount, category):
    if category == 'fruits':
        print 'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: {0}.'.format(itemcount)
```

Once you have more item categories, you might want to consider writing your function like this (or similar) to allow for some more flexibility:

```
def item_checkout(itemcount, category):
    print 'the number of {0} items in the grocery bag is: {1}'.format(category, itemcount)
```

Or if you want a general checkout function, let it take of list of `(itemcount, category)` tuples:

```
def total_checkout(items):
    'items: list of (itemcount, category) tuples'
    for itemcount, category in items:
        print 'the number of {0} items in the grocery bag is: {1}'.format(category, itemcount)
```

Demo:

```
>>> total_checkout([(5, 'banana'), (2, 'fruit'), (7, 'sirup')])
the number of banana items in the grocery bag is: 5
the number of fruit items in the grocery bag is: 2
the number of sirup items in the grocery bag is: 7
```

Comment: I just realized bananas are fruit.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a set of similarly named variables should be combined into a single list. (For this, we'll ignore that the values themselves are similar, and the other answers are superior.)

```
groceryfruits = [
    'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 1.',
    'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 2.',
    'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 3.',
    'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 4.',
    'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 5.',
    'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 6.',
    'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 7.',
    'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 8.',
    'The number of fruit(s) in the grocery bag is: 9.'
]

def checkout(itemcount, category):
    if category == "fruits":
        if 1 <= itemcount <= 9:
            # List indices start at 0
            print groceryfruits[i-1]


checkout(9, "fruits")
```